# Oracle SQL Partition range all instead of range single

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, database-partitioning

I created a partition table by the date, where I divided createdate (hen the customer created an account).

```
CREATE TABLE PARTITIONED_customer (
                        customerId number(10) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, 
                        firstName  varchar2(50), 
                        lastName   varchar2(50), 
                        email      varchar2(50), 
                        createDate date, 
                        active     char(1),
                        PRIMARY KEY (customerId))
                        PARTITION BY RANGE (createDate)
                        INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
                        (PARTITION first_quater_2018 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-04-2018','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION second_quater_2018 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-07-2018','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION third_quater_2018 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-10-2018','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION fourth_quater_2018 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-01-2019','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION first_quater_2019 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-04-2019','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION second_quater_2019 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-07-2019','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION third_quater_2019 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-10-2019','dd-MM-yyyy')),
                        PARTITION fourth_quater_2019 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01-01-2020','dd-MM-yyyy')));
```

Here is the SQL query where I want to know when the customer created an account. I know that the query is not fully correct, sorry for that in advance

```
select c.createdate, c.firstname, c.lastname, round(sum(p.amount)) as spentmoney
from PARTITIONED_customer c
join PARTITIONED_rental r
on c.customerid = r.customerid
join PARTITIONED_payment_amount p
on p.rentalid = r.rentalid
where  c.createdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-05-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') 
AND TO_DATE('01-06-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') 
or (select round(sum(pp.amount)) from PARTITIONED_payment_amount pp
        join PARTITIONED_rental rr
        on rr.rentalid = pp.rentalid
        where rr.customerid=c.customerid) < 50 
group by c.firstname, c.lastname,c.createdate
order by c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

[image: Explainer]
Explainer shows partition range all, instead of single. How could it be fixed?

I checked the partition by itself with a simple query, and it was fine. So, I think that something wrong with the query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is doing a TABLE ACCESS FULL on PARTITIONED_CUSTOMER so of course it must search all the partitions. I suggest creating on index on the partitioning key:

```
CREATE INDEX PARTITIONED_CUSTOMER_1
  ON PARTITIONED_CUSTOMER (CREATEDATE)
  LOCAL;
```

If you really want to you can specify a PARTITION clause in your query:

```
select c.createdate, c.firstname, c.lastname, round(sum(p.amount)) as spentmoney
  from PARTITIONED_customer PARTITION (second_quater_2019) c
  INNER join PARTITIONED_rental r
    on c.customerid = r.customerid
  INNER join PARTITIONED_payment_amount p
    on p.rentalid = r.rentalid
  where  c.createdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-05-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') AND 
         TO_DATE('01-06-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') or
         (select round(sum(pp.amount))
            from PARTITIONED_payment_amount pp
            INNER join PARTITIONED_rental rr
              on rr.rentalid = pp.rentalid
            where rr.customerid=c.customerid) < 50 
  group by c.firstname, c.lastname,c.createdate
  order by c.firstname, c.lastname
```

Also - you have `AND` and `OR` conditions in this query which are not fully parenthesized. The order in which the `AND` and `OR` are evaluated may not be what you think it is. Did you mean

```
         (c.createdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-05-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') AND 
          TO_DATE('01-06-2019','dd-MM-yyyy')) or
         (select round(sum(pp.amount))
            from PARTITIONED_payment_amount pp
            INNER join PARTITIONED_rental rr
              on rr.rentalid = pp.rentalid
            where rr.customerid=c.customerid) < 50
```

or did you mean

```
         c.createdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-05-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') AND 
         (TO_DATE('01-06-2019','dd-MM-yyyy') or
          (select round(sum(pp.amount))
             from PARTITIONED_payment_amount pp
             INNER join PARTITIONED_rental rr
               on rr.rentalid = pp.rentalid
             where rr.customerid=c.customerid) < 50)
```

If you mix `AND` and `OR` like this it's always a good idea to use parentheses to group the operations as you want them, or you may not get the results you expect.